# View state in not working inside the static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a web method for calling a function from java script.In my aspx code behind have a view state["cust_id"]. I want to use this cust_id in public static method.But i can't do this. Please help me to do this.

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void add_plan_items(string plans)
  {
    string cust_id = Convert.ToString(ViewState["cust_id"]);//Error : object reference is required for non-static ...
  }
```

Comment: Well, dont make it `static` then! Also, IIRC, `WebMethod` does not work on static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Error is because `ViewSate` object is attached with the page. Thats why you cannot use it in the static method..

Instead of this you need to pass `cust_id` as parameter to the method , so your method will be like

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void add_plan_items(string plans,string cust_id)
  {
     //your code
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am calling this function from ascx page.The ascx page doesn't contain the cust_id.Only this page having the cust_id.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of view state we can use session in  web services.
just enable session true in web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static Boolean AddRecord(string contextKey)
{
    List<MID1> MID1s = HttpContext.Current.Session["MID1s"] as List<MID1>;

    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        Boolean RetVal = false;
        MID1s = new List<MID1>();
        MID1 objMID1 = new MID1();
        objMID1.ItemID = 1;
        MID1s.Add(objMID1);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["MID1s"] = MID1s;
        return RetVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar question here
[How could I access the ViewState of the current page using HttpContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309075/how-could-i-access-the-viewstate-of-the-current-page-using-httpcontext)

Which suggest that I can access the view state using `httpcontext`

```
    private static T GetViewState<T>(string name)
    {
        return (T) ((BasePage)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).PageViewState[name];
    }
```

I added a new PageViewState property and let all my pages inherit from my BasePage to expose ViewState then being able to get or set it.